# Как удалить куки(выход пользователя с системы)

Tags: php, cookie

**Скачать все файлы:** [Скачать](http://rgho.st/private/6qYM7xx9t/b71aefc9003cc6288db1e2be48f3149a)

**Задача:**

1. Для начала создайте несколько полезных функций и выделите их в отдельный файл:

   1. Функция getUsersList() пусть возвращает массив всех пользователей и хэшей их паролей
   2. Функция existsUser($login) проверяет - существует ли пользователь с заданным логином?
   3. Функция сheckPassword($login, $password) пусть возвращает true тогда, когда существует пользователь с указанным логином и введенный им пароль прошел проверку
2. Добавьте функцию getCurrentUser() которая возвращает либо имя вошедшего на сайт пользователя, либо null
3. Добавьте к проекту страничку login.php, которая:

   1. ЕСЛИ пользователь уже вошел (см. пункт 2), ТО редирект на главную страницу
   2. ЕСЛИ пользователь не вошел - отображает форму входа
   3. ЕСЛИ введены данные в форму входа - проверяем их (см. пункт 1.3) и ЕСЛИ проверка прошла, ТО запоминаем информацию о вошедшем пользователе

**Проблема:**
  Хочу сделать выход пользователя с сайта, но не могу удалить куки, кусочек кода из login.php:

```
<?php
if (0 !== count($_COOKIE)) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let linkExit = document.getElementById('exit');
        linkExit.addEventListener('onclick', function () {
            <?php
            setcookie(key($_COOKIE), $_COOKIE[key($_COOKIE)], time() - 100);
            $_COOKIE = [];
            ?>
        })
    </script>
<?php
}
echo 'Вы уже вошли!' . '<br/>';?>
```

Т.к. я вставил кусочек js(чтобы отследить нажатие кнопки выхода), это не позволяет куки удалиться

**index.php:**

```
<?php
    include __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
    if (checkPassword($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'])) {
        setcookie($_POST['login'], getUsersList()[$_POST['login']]);
        echo 'Вы вошли как ' . key($_COOKIE);
    } else {
        echo 'Вы не вошли или ввели неверные данные'; ?>
        <br/>
        <a href="login.php">Войти</a>
<?php
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php
    if (0 !== count($_COOKIE)) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let linkExit = document.getElementById('exit');
        linkExit.addEventListener('onclick', function () {
            <?php
                setcookie(key($_COOKIE), $_COOKIE[key($_COOKIE)], time() - 100);
                $_COOKIE = [];
            ?>
        })
    </script>
<?php
    echo 'Вы уже вошли!' . '<br/>';?>
<a href="login.php" id="exit">Выйти</a>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Логин</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        } else {?>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <p>Войдите на сайт!</p>
            <input type="text" name="login">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <button type="submit">Войти!</button>
        </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php:**

```
<?php
    function getUsersList () {
        $arr = [
            'admin' => '12345',
            'lepta' => '54321',
        ];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $elem) {
            $arr[$key] = password_hash($elem, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    function existsUser($login) {
        $arr = getUsersList();
        $result = false;
        foreach ($arr as $key => $elem) {
            if ($key === $login) {
                $result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function checkPassword($login, $password) {
        $arr = getUsersList();
        $result = false;
        foreach ($arr as $key => $elem) {
            if ($key === $login && password_verify($password, $elem)) {
                $result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в колбеке js указан php код. Если в браузере посмотреть исходный код `login.php` - можно увидеть, что будет что-то типа такого:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let linkExit = document.getElementById('exit');
    linkExit.addEventListener('onclick', function () {
    })
</script>
```

потому что php код отработает и ничего не выведет.

Возможное решение: создать ссылку на `logout.php`, которая появляется если пользователь залогинился. И собственно в `logout.php` чистить куки посредством php:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$userLogin])) {
    unset($_COOKIE[$userLogin]);
    setcookie($userLogin, null, -1, '/');
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Я уже вместо php метода, очистил куки посредством js